# Many to many sequence prediction with different sequence length

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My problem is to predict a sequence of values `(t_0, t_1, ... t_{n_post-1})` given the previous timesteps `(t_{-n_pre}, t_{-n_pre+1} ... t_{-1})` with Keras' LSTM layer.

Keras supports the the following two cases well:

- `n_post == 1` (many to one forecast)
- `n_post == n_pre` (many to many
  forecast with equal sequence lengths)

But not the version where `n_post < n_pre`.

To illustrate what I need, I built a simple toy example using a sine wave.

**Many to one model forecast**

With the following model:

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(input_dim=1, output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=False))  
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))   
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

predictions look like this:
[image: Sine: Many to one LSTM]

**Many to many model forecast with n_pre == n_post**

The network learns to fit a sine wave with n_pre == n_post pretty well with a model like this:

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(input_dim=1, output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))   
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

[image: Sine Many to Many model forecast using n_post==n_pre]

**Many to many model forecast with n_post < n_pre**

But now, assume my data looks like this:
dataX or input: `(nb_samples, nb_timesteps, nb_features) -> (1000, 50, 1)`
dataY or output: `(nb_samples, nb_timesteps, nb_features) -> (1000, 10, 1)`

After some research I found a way on how to handle these input sizes in Keras, using a model like this:

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(input_dim=1, output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=False))  
model.add(RepeatVector(10))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))   
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

But the predictions are really bad:
[image: Many to many with n_post < n_pre]

Now my questions are:

- How can I build a model with `n_post < n_pre` that doesn't lose information because it has a `return_sequences=False`?
- Using `n_post == n_pre` and then cropping the output (after training) doesn't work for me because it would still try to fit on a lot of timesteps while only the first few can be predicted with a neural network (the others are not nicely correlated and would distort the result)

Comment: How many steps ahead do you want to predict?

Comment: In this particular example, 10. But it could be anything like: 1 < n_post < n_pre

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After asking this question on the Keras Github page, I got an answer, which I post here for completeness.

The solution is to use a second LSTM layer, after shaping the output with `RepeatVector` to the desired number of output steps.

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(input_dim=1, output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=False))  
model.add(RepeatVector(10))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))   
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

The predictions are looking better now and look like this:
[image]

Comment: The discussion on GitHub is available there, as well as OP's code: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6063